# Can a docker container 'go to sleep'?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am running a server inside a docker container. I start it by using `docker-compose up -d` which works fine, i can access the Server. After some time however I receive a 503 - service unavailable error.

When I then perform any docker command e. g. `docker ps`  or `docker logs` the server runs perfectly again. `docker ps` shows that the container was created days ago, but  Status says `Up 1 second`. Is there any way for me to know what state my docker was in before? How does `docker ps` change the status?

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:12.1
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
      POSTGRES_USER: user
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    volumes:
      - /home/user/data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
  web:
    restart: always
    build: .
    environment:
      JPDA_ADDRESS: 8001
      JPDA_TRANSPORT: dt_socket
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - 80:8080
      - 8001:8001
    volumes:
    - /home/user/data/images:/data/images
networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-8-slim as java-build-stage

WORKDIR /app/build
COPY . .

RUN mvn clean package -am -DskipTests -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -P deployment

# create the image to run the tomcat
FROM tomcat:9.0.30-jdk8-openjdk-slim as myname-build

ADD docker-resources/tomcat-users.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml
ADD docker-resources/index.html /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/index.jsp
COPY --from=java-build-stage /app/build/deployment/target/myname.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/myname.war

CMD ["catalina.sh", "jpda" ,"run"]
```

Comment: Probably it crashed but you have some sort of [`restart_policy`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart_policy) configured. Without your `docker-compose.yaml` that's going to be hard to guess

Comment: I've added my ```docker-compose.yaml```

Comment: It looks like you have `restart: always` set. So whenever your container crashes it will restart.

Comment: How can I check the reason for why the container crashes? ```docker logs mycontainer -f``` does not show anything. Is there a way to restart the container automatically - without me having to do a ```docker ps```?

Comment: And is there a way for me to know whether my container crashed or the application within?

Comment: The container is the application. Docker is a was to run a Linux process with some isolation settings (namespaces and cgroups). When your application running as pid 1 crashes, by definition, the container exits.

Comment: @BMitch Ok thanks. Is there some way to restart the application automatically without any intervention in that case?

Comment: Docker did with the restart policy, which is why it says "up 1 second" rather than "exited...".

Comment: @BMitch yes but I still had to perform a ```docker ps```. Is there a way to restart it automatically?

Comment: Except docker does restart automatically without you looking, the ps command does not affect the restart policy. I suspect your container is in a crash loop.

Comment: @BMitch when I perform a ps command it does restart and continues to work fine

Comment: Please verify the docker engine is running before running `docker ps`. Check `systemctl status docker`.

Comment: @BMitch ```systemctl status docker```shows it's not running

Comment: Looks like the same issue from another question. You'll want to debug why docker is crashing of it's not happening on a reboot.